# I want to use jest to write vue-next ,but I meet some matters

Tags: typescript, vue.js, jestjs, vuejs3

I don‘t know how to change this, I started to use jest, so I need help .And I hope get some tips about use jest or give me some great examples

1、 my hooks

```
import {ref} from 'vue-demi'
const useLatest = <T>(num: T):{readonly current: T} => {
  const refLatest = ref(num)
  refLatest.current = num.value
  return refLatest
}
export {useLatest}
```

2、my test

```
import {useLatest}  from '../src'
import {ref} from 'vue-demi'

const count = ref<number>(0)

describe('test useLatest', () => {
  const current1 = useLatest(count)
  test('test current value', async () => { 
    expect(current1).toBe(0)
  })
})
```

3、my error

```
  ● test useLatest › encountered a declaration exception

    TypeError: Cannot add property current, object is not extensible

      2 | const useLatest = <T>(num: T):{readonly current: T} => {
      3 |   const refLatest = ref(num)
    > 4 |   refLatest.current = num.value
        |   ^
      5 |   return refLatest
      6 | }
      7 | export {useLatest}
```

Comment: The tip that is specific to Jest is to move `current1 = useLatest(count)` to either a test or `beforeEach`. You don't want to reuse the same object between tests.

Answer (score 0):

In contrast to React refs that have `current` property, Vue composition API refs have `value` property.

It should be:

```
const refLatest = ref(num)
refLatest.value = num.value
```

and

```
expect(isRef(current1)).toBe(true)
expect(current1.value).toBe(0)
```

And the mistake could be detected at compilation time by using the correct type:

```
const useLatest = <T>(num: T): Ref<T> => {
```